# Compilation Error : expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, syntax-error

Which is something I really don't understand: I see nothing which actually makes this error prone.

Here's the class:

```
namespace Engine_Main {

class SceneManager
{
public:
    SceneManager(Engine& engine);
    void createScene();
private:
    Ogre::SceneManager * mSceneMgr;
};


}
```

Along with a few other classes for reference:

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <OGRE/OgreSceneManager.h>
#include <OGRE/OgreRoot.h>
#include "scenemanager.h"
#include "playerinput.h"

namespace Engine_Main {

class Engine
{
public:
    Engine();
    ~Engine();

    void initGameLoop();

    PlayerInput * getPlayerInput();
    PlayerMovement * getPlayerMovement();
    Ogre::Root * getOgreRoot();

private:

    //fields
    PlayerInput * mPInput;
    PlayerMovement * mPMovement;
    Ogre::Root * mRoot;
    //methods
    void registerInput();
    void createScene();
    void renderPosition();
};

}

#endif // ENGINE_H

#include "engine.h"


namespace Engine_Main {

    /**********/
    /* PUBLIC */
    /**********/

    PlayerMovement * Engine::getPlayerMovement() {
        return mPMovement;
    }

    PlayerInput * Engine::getPlayerInput() {
        return mPInput;
    }

    Engine::Engine() {
        mPInput = new PlayerInput();
        mPMovement = new PlayerMovement();
        mRoot = new Ogre::Root("cfg/plugins.cfg", "cfg/engine.cfg", "cfg/engine.log");
    }

    Engine::~Engine(){
        if (mPInput) {
            delete mPInput;
        }

        if (mRoot) {
            delete mRoot;
        }
    }

    void Engine::createScene() {

    }

}
```

**My question**

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the errors and the line numbers? It would be easy.

Comment: It's hard to answer this with the information given; you haven't really told us the context of the error. What file and line number? What is the text of that file?

Comment: Just say `delete mPInput;` etc. It does exactly what you need. (Though normally I'd strongly recommend to never use `delete` at all and instead use a single-responsibility wrapper class such as `unique_ptr`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why \`&\` is not allowed in C, but in C++ in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083766/why-is-not-allowed-in-c-but-in-c-in-this-case)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you missing a (forward) declaration of `Engine` in `"scenemanager.h"`?  When the compiler parses:

```
...
SceneManager(Engine&);
...
```

it needs a declaration of the `Engine` type.  You may need a forward declaration like `class Engine;` before the declaration of the `SceneManager` class.

Comment: I tried what you said, and that didn't work; I just put `class Engine;` before the declaration of the class, and I'm still getting the same error. I actually get an additional error: `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘}’ token` which basically means I need curly bracers I think. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Holland You may define a class at a later position in the code, but you need it some time before. For example, a circular reference between 2 different classes is only possible using a forward-declaration. `class Foo; class Bar { Foo* ptr; }; class Foo { Bar* ptr; };` Note that you can only **point** to a forward-declared class.

Comment: @NiklasR 
That's interesting, because while there was a circular reference happening before, there isn't anymore and I'm still getting the error.