# Why `&` is not allowed in C, but in C++ in this case? Is there any defference?

Tags: c++, c

Here is my C code, I use `void InitList(List &L);` However Code::Blocks`s buildlog has an error:

> expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MaxSize 10
typedef int ElementType;

struct SeqList;
typedef struct SeqList List;
void InitList(List &L);

struct SeqList
{
    ElementType *data;
    int CurLength;
};

/*----------------------------------*/

void InitList(List &L)
{
    (&L)->data = malloc(sizeof(ElementType)*MaxSize); 
    (&L)->CurLength = 0;
}


int main()
{
    List L;
    InitList(&L);
    return 0;
}
```

But I tried in C++, there is no error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define InitSize 100
typedef int ElementType;

struct SeqList;
typedef struct SeqList List;
void InitList(List &L);

struct SeqList
{
    ElementType *data;
    int CurLength;
};


/*----------------------------------*/

void InitList(List &L)
{
    L.data = new ElementType[InitSize]; //L.data = malloc(...)
    L.CurLength = 0;
}

int main()
{
    List L;
    InitList(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because C++ provides a *reference* while C does not and `'&'` is used as the syntax for a reference.... See , e.g. [Reference initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)

Comment: Because C++ is not C. C doesn't support references. `&` in C means bitwise AND. That makes no sense in a variable or parameter declaration. I hate telling people to read the spec, but... if you'd googled the operator, you'd have found multiple pages explaining this.

Comment: *Unary* `&` is the address-of operator in C, not bitwise AND.  The same in C++, but the symbol is also used in declarative contexts in C++ to indicate a reference.

Comment: lots of duplicates if you search the error message: [error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12904091/995714), [error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20831221/995714), [Error expected ')' trying to pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38132464/995714), [error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token| on a simple C program found online](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19782983/995714)...

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass that in a function declaration in C. You need to be using * if you want to reference the pointer to that data.

```c
void InitList(List *L)
{
    L->data = malloc(sizeof(ElementType)*MaxSize); 
    L->CurLength = 0;
}
```

And then

```c
List *L;
InitList (&L);
```

Comment: Also consider `calloc(MaxSize, sizeof(ElementType)`.

Comment: Excellent idea as well!

Comment: More likely, I think, "And then: `List L; InitList(&L);`" — otherwise, nothing changes in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

In `void InitList(List &L);`, `L` is being passed by **reference**.  C does not support references, that is a C++ feature.  In C, you need to pass `L` by pointer instead (which is exactly what your `main()` is trying to do when using `List L; InitList(&L);`, but the declaration of `InitList()` is wrong for that), eg:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MaxSize 10
typedef int ElementType;

struct SeqList;
typedef struct SeqList List;
void InitList(List *L);
void CleanupList(List *L);

struct SeqList
{
    ElementType *data;
    int CurLength;
};

/*----------------------------------*/

void InitList(List *L)
{
    L->data = malloc(sizeof(ElementType)*MaxSize); 
    L->CurLength = 0;
}

void CleanupList(List *L)
{
    free(L->data); 
    L->CurLength = 0;
}

int main()
{
    List L;
    InitList(&L);
    ...
    CleanupList(&L);
    return 0;
}
```